# Next Auth saving different JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, next.js13, next-auth

I'm having trouble with Next-Auth. Sometimes it throws the error:

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n'
```

The JWT I get it from Firebase authentication, but the problem is that I checked my cookies and the JSON web token retrieved from the session is different from the one saved in cookies. This is giving me a hard time trying to set up a server redirection for my web app because of this error. The middleware always shows that the token is null using getToken(). The useSession() works for me but sometimes, out of nowhere, I get redirected to the login due to the JWT error.